# Why child view not generating or responding to any event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, user-controls

I am creating one user control by inheriting from `UIControl`. I wanted to show `slidingViewController` on `self.viewController`. User control will be part of `self.viewController` and `viewController` is weak reference in UIControl (user control).

My requirment is simple, I want to show one view over another, which is working fine. Problem is, newly loaded view, is not responding to any of the events.

I have used following code to load one view over another.

```
   id storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

   self.slidingViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlidingDrawerViewController"];

   self.slidingViewController.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.slidingViewController.view.frame, 0, -self.slidingViewController.view.frame.size.height);


   [self.viewController addChildViewController:self.slidingViewController];


   [self.viewController.view addSubview:self.slidingViewController.view];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
id storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

self.slidingViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlidingDrawerViewController"];

[self addChildViewController:self.slidingViewController];

self.slidingViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:self.slidingViewController.view];
[self.slidingViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
```